# Mostrar en número como horas en formato "hh:mm" en Power BI

Tags: powerbi, microsoft

En la siguiente tabla hay tres columnas que muestran las horas en formato numérico.

[image: imagen01]

Luego cada uno de los valores de ellas deberían estar en formato "hh:mm", por ejemplo el primer valor de la columna "Horas YTD" luego de "FTE" es 5,26; pero lo que debería mostrarse es "5:16". Lo mismo 105310,44; debería mostrar "105310:27".

Como se puede observar las columnas muestran valores acumulados en sumatorias, **¿hay alguna manera de que se puedan mostrar esas columnas en formato "hh:mm" aunque las horas excedan de 24 y también conservar los minutos al hacer sumatorias?**

Answer (score 0):

En las medidas que representen horas y minutos las debes identificar como tal. Para ello seleccionas la medida, en Desktop le dices que se trata (Tipo de datos) de una hora y seleccionas el formato a mostrar. En la imagen (con la versión de noviembre de Power BI Desktop) te lo he señalado en rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]